# LZ4 library decompressed data upper bound size estimation

Tags: c, compression, snappy, lz4

I'm using [LZ4](https://code.google.com/p/lz4/) library and when decompressing data with

```
int LZ4_decompress_safe (const char* source, char* dest, int compressedSize, int maxDecompressedSize);
```

I want to estimate maximum decompressed data size. But I can not find reverse function of

```
int LZ4_compressBound(int isize);
```

with which I can determine the upper bound for decompressed data, which to provide to last parameter `maxDecompressedSize`, of decompressing function.

Other compression libraries like [snappy](https://github.com/google/snappy) for example, provides such function.

```
bool GetUncompressedLength(Source* source, uint32* result);
```

What can I do if I have not capability to save initial data size (before compression), and if I don't want to be over pessimistic for the size of the buffer which I must allocate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The maximum compression ratio of LZ4 is 255, so a guaranteed over-estimation of decompressed data size is 255 times input size.

That's obviously too much to be really useful, hence the reason why there is no "reverse LZ4_compressBound()" function available.

I'm afraid there is no other way than to save, or know, the uncompressed size. The LZ4 "raw" compression format doesn't define a way to save such information, because optimal choice is application specific. For example, some application know in advance that no block can be > 16KB, so they can use maxDecompressedSize = 16 KB when calling LZ4_decompress_safe().

Now, if you are looking for an envelope format that will take in charge such responsibility, you could either create your own custom one, or use the LZ4 Framing format : http://fastcompression.blogspot.fr/2013/04/lz4-streaming-format-final.html (also present as LZ4_Framing_Format.html within source package). Alas, the library able to generate and read this format is currently in beta stage (https://github.com/Cyan4973/lz4/tree/frame)

Answer (score 10):

Just for reference, *n* bytes of LZ4 compressed data can represent up to 24 + 255(*n* - 10) uncompressed bytes, which is the case of a run of that many bytes.  *n* must be at least ten to make a valid stream that includes a literal, a match, and then five literals at the end per the specification.  So the decompress bound function could be something like `(n << 8) - n - 2526`.

The maximum compression ratio is then: 255 - 2526 / *n*, which asymptotically approaches 255 for arbitrarily large *n*.

Comment: I've never taken the time to calculate the precise limits as clearly as you did in this post. Thanks for the simple formulas !