# How to know when the output buffer is too small when decompressing with LZ4?

Tags: c, compression, lz4

The documentation of [`LZ4_decompress_safe`](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/lib/lz4.h#L133) says:

> ```
> /*! LZ4_decompress_safe() :
>     compressedSize : is the precise full size of the compressed block.
>     maxDecompressedSize : is the size of destination buffer, which must be already allocated.
>     return : the number of bytes decompressed into destination buffer (necessarily <= maxDecompressedSize)
>              If destination buffer is not large enough, decoding will stop and output an error code (<0).
>              If the source stream is detected malformed, the function will stop decoding and return a negative result.
>              This function is protected against buffer overflow exploits, including malicious data packets.
>              It never writes outside output buffer, nor reads outside input buffer.
> */
> LZ4LIB_API int LZ4_decompress_safe (const char* source, char* dest, int compressedSize, int maxDecompressedSize);
> ```

But doesn't specify how to distinguish whether the issue is with a too small destination buffer or from malformed input/bad combination of parameters/...

In the case where I don't know what the target decompressed size is, how can I know whether I should retry with a bigger buffer, or not?

Answer (score 4):

There is an [issue opened](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/issues/156) about this, and for now there is no public API to distinguish between errors.

---

As a **heuristic**, looking at [the code](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/lib/lz4.c#L1239) shows the possible return values:

> ```
>     /* end of decoding */
>     if (endOnInput)
>        return (int) (((char*)op)-dest);     /* Nb of output bytes decoded */
>     else
>        return (int) (((const char*)ip)-source);   /* Nb of input bytes read */
>
>     /* Overflow error detected */
> _output_error:
>     return (int) (-(((const char*)ip)-source))-1;
> ```

So there are only 2 cases:

- either the decoding was successful, and you get a positive result (whose signification depends on whether you are in full or partial mode)
- or the decoding was unsuccessful and you get a negative result

In the case of the negative result, the value is `-(position_in_input + 1)`.

This suggests that guessing whether the destination buffer was too small can be accomplished with a good likelihood of success by retrying with a (much) bigger buffer, and checking whether the failure occurs in the same position:

- if the second decompression attempt succeeds, you're good!
- if the second decompression attempt fails at the same position, then the issue is likely with the input,
- otherwise, you have to try with a bigger buffer again.

Or otherwise said, as long as the result differs, try again, otherwise, there's your result.

---

**Limitation**

The input pointer does not necessarily advance one byte at a time, it may advance `length` bytes in two places where `length` is read from the input and unbounded.

If decoding fails because the output buffer was too small, and the new output buffer is still too small for `length`, then decoding will fail in the same position even though the input is not (necessarily) malformed.

If false positives are an issue, then one may attempt to:

- decode the `length`, by checking the input stream at the position returned,
- simply allocate `255 * <input size> - 2526` as per [Mark Adler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25755758/147192), which is reasonable for small inputs.

Comment: Sir, I wish to talk to you about something, Can We Chat?