# How to use LWJGL's LZ4 bindings to compress and decompress

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am attempting to create two helper methods, one to compress and one to decompress. These methods should use LWJGL's LZ4 bindings to accomplish the compression/decompression.

They mostly work already but the byte array that get's returned after decompressing has trailing zeros.

```
import static org.lwjgl.util.lz4.LZ4.LZ4_compressBound;
import static org.lwjgl.util.lz4.LZ4.LZ4_compress_default;
import static org.lwjgl.util.lz4.LZ4.LZ4_decompress_safe;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public static byte[] compress(byte[] data) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(data.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        buffer.put(data[i]);
    }
    buffer.flip();

    ByteBuffer destination = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(LZ4_compressBound(buffer.remaining()));
    destination.clear();

    LZ4_compress_default(buffer, destination);

    return getByteArrayFromByteBuffer(destination);
}

public static byte[] decompress(byte[] data) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(data.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        buffer.put(data[i]);
    }
    buffer.flip();

    ByteBuffer destination = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(LZ4_compressBound(buffer.remaining()));
    destination.clear();

    LZ4_decompress_safe(buffer, destination);

    return getByteArrayFromByteBuffer(destination);
}

public static byte[] getByteArrayFromByteBuffer(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
    byte[] bytesArray = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
    byteBuffer.get(bytesArray, 0, bytesArray.length);
    return bytesArray;
}
```

The result after running compress(decompress(SOME DATA)), 
is: [SOME_DATA, 0, 0, 0].

The first half of the data is correct but for some reason extra zeros are added. This is probably due to the ByteBuffers not being correctly setup, but I am unsure. Either way how can I remove these extra zeros?

Also unfortunately [this](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/blob/master/modules/samples/src/test/java/org/lwjgl/demo/util/lz4/HelloLZ4.java) is the only link I could find that shows an example on how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, during compression you are currently using the result of [`LZ4_compressBound(...)`](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/util/lz4/LZ4.html#LZ4_compressBound(int)) to define the initial capacity of your destination buffer. While this is correct, you have to keep in mind that this is only the Worst-Case size of the compressed data. The actual amount of bytes written by [`LZ4_compress_default(...)`](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/util/lz4/LZ4.html#LZ4_compress_default(java.nio.ByteBuffer,java.nio.ByteBuffer)) is the return value of said function and likely less than the bound. Thus you need to trim your destination buffer to match that size.

```java
int compressedSize = LZ4_compress_default(buffer, destination);
destination.limit(compressedSize);
destination = destination.slice();
```

Additionally you have a similar bug in your decompression:
You can not use `LZ4_compressBound(...)` to calculate the capacity of your destination buffer. Instead, you need to store the size of the decompressed data elsewhere. (In theory you could use `compressedSize * 255` but this is extremely impractial since that compression ratio is almost never achieved and thus leads to a huge amount of wasted resources. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25751871/11547351))
And again you need to respect the return value of [`LZ4_decompress_safe`](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/util/lz4/LZ4.html#LZ4_decompress_safe(java.nio.ByteBuffer,java.nio.ByteBuffer)) which is the actual size of the decompressed data.